# Create view put table on the right side of the screen

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I having MVC project with User entity which have one to many relationship with address,

I use code first and by scaffolding generate the view . in the create operation I see in the left side of the screen the fields from userid until working at .what I need is very simple,in the right side of the screen create table on the create view which is currently empty with one column that user can add to address,how should I do that?

Im very new to MVC and didn't find any documentation on how to add control like table in the right side of the create vied.

**I try something like this without success
the table is in the bottom of the screen**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkingAt, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkingAt)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkingAt)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

//This is the table which I want to be in the right side of the screen
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adress)
        </th>
</table>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with MVC. Try control the view using proper CSS. For this particular situation try using css properties like: clear, float etc. Check these: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_class-clear

Comment: Why don't you try with **@Html.Partial("YourAddressView", model.Address)**. this might help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table class="table  col-md-offset-11 col-md-10">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            </th>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks,Voted up ,I see that the table place was change to the right,how should I change it to up and down,I want it to be in the right in the upper side of the screen,currently its down